# How to access device apps from flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile-development

Is there any way to access the details of apps installed in the device and access its privacy permission details (ex: how much access the GMAIL have in our device?) from the flutter app?

Answer (score 2):

At this time there no official library available to retrieve the packages installed in the device. You can check the unofficial plugin, [package manager plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_package_manager#-readme-tab-) in [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/).

Some of the limitations are ..

- This is not the official plugin.
- Supports only Android platform
- Minimum supported Android version is 22.

But you can give it a try if those constraints are fine for you.

Sample usage

```
import 'package:flutter_package_manager/flutter_package_manager.dart';

Future<List> getInstalledPackages() async {
  List packages = await FlutterPackageManager.getInstalledPackages();
  return packages;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will try this package!

Answer (score 1):

You can try a package named `device_apps`.

It is a plugin to list installed applications on an Android device (**⚠️ iOS is not supported**).

[Check this](https://pub.dev/packages/device_apps/example)

You can get

- App Version
- App name
- Apk File Path
- Data Directory
- Installation date and time

Note : Though it was better then other packages , I found that it takes a lot of time (10-15sec) to intract with the Android system.