# Is there a way to launch notes application in flutter from button click?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `button` in my app. On click of the button, I want the notes app in the device to get launched whether iOS or Android. I there a way around this with flutter? I haven't discovered any solution yet.

Comment: here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61318123/how-to-access-device-apps-from-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is this plugin `external_app_launcher`  will helps you to open another app from your app by providing PackageName for Android and URLscheme for IOS [external_app_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/external_app_launcher)